# How do I repeat a calculation for each row of a matrix in R?

Tags: r, apply

I am very very new to programming and R. I have tried to find an answer to my question, but part of the problem is I don't know exactly what to search.

I am trying to repeat a calculation (statistical distance) for each row of a matrix. Here is what I have so far:

```
pollution1 <-as.matrix(pollution[,5:6])
ss <- var(pollution1)
ssinv <- solve(ss)
xbar <- colMeans(pollution1)
t(pollution1[1,]-xbar)%*%ssinv%*%(pollution1[1,]-xbar)
```

This gets me only the first statistical distance, but I don't want to retype this line with a different matrix row to get all of them.

From what I have read, I may need a loop or to use `apply()`, but haven't had success on my own. Any help with this, and advice on how to search for help so I don't need to post, would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! can you reproduce an example to help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just using `apply`

```
apply(pollution1, 1, function(i) t(i-xbar) %*% ssinv %*% (i-xbar))
```

---

Also, it's helpful if you make your example reproducible, for example:

```
pollution1 = matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=2)
ss = var(pollution1)
ssinv = solve(ss)
xbar = colMeans(pollution1)
t(pollution1[1,]-xbar) %*% ssinv %*% (pollution1[1,]-xbar)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider the `mahalanobis` function: from `?mahalanobis`,

> Returns the squared Mahalanobis distance of all rows in ‘x’ and
>        the vector mu = ‘center’ with respect to Sigma = ‘cov’.  This is
>        (for vector ‘x’) defined as
>
> ```
>                   D^2 = (x - mu)' Sigma^-1 (x - mu)
> ```

Of course, it's good to learn how to use `apply` too ...